# How to load Outlook 365 Add in on startup to RUN a specific code in Add in?

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin

I'm developing an outlook Add-in in Visual Studio(JavaScript). It's 70 % completed. I want to run my add-in's in the background when the outlook app starts.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a [Taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) automatically, but AFAIK to run commands in the background with officejs, the user has to interact with the addin. COM Addins should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Lumpentein How to load Outlook 365 Add in on startup? Have you any idea about it?